# Como puedo obtener los datos de un select en javascript y evaluar ese valor y mandarlo a un archivo php desde ajax

Tags: php, javascript, ajax, select

Tengo un select y tiene 4 valores (uno por option) y lo que quiero es obtener el valor de ese option y evaluarlo con un switch ejemplo

Café Latte

y el valor de ese option lo pongo en un switch y si es 1 tengo que obtener el texto y hacer una operación y después convertirlo a json y mandarlo a un archivo php por medio de Ajax intente algo pero me recarga la pagina lo cual no lo debe de hacer .
Se que hay mejores maneras de hacerlo pero no se me ocurrió de otra manera de solucionarlo
espero haberme explicado

```js
  function pedido() {
            Swal.fire(
                'Good job!',
                'You clicked the button!',
                'success'
            )
        }
        $(function () {
            /*Evitar funciones in line*/
            $('#Opcion').on('change', function () {
                /*Referencia al option seleccionado*/
                let mSelect = $('option:selected', this);
                let opcion = mSelect.val();
                let Nombre = mSelect.text();
                let valor = $('#cantidad').val();

                let postData = {
                    Nombre: Nombre,
                    cantidad: valor,
                    Precio: mSelect.data('precio'),
                    Total: valor * mSelect.data('precio')
                };

                console.log(postData);

                $.ajax({
                    url: 'php/procesos/insertarProductos.php',
                    method: 'post',
                    dataType: 'json',
                    data: postData
                }).done(function (data) {
                    pedido();
                    console.log(data);
                })
            });
        });
```

```css
.areaProductos {
    margin: 2rem;
    width: 100%;
    height: 50rem;
    background: #c7c7c7;
}

.productos {
    display: flex;
    margin: 2rem;
    justify-content: center;
}

.productosgrid {
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: repeat(3, 1fr);
}

.card {
    width: 30rem;
    height: 33rem;
    background: #EAE7DE;
    margin: 3rem;
}

.card img {
    background-position: center;
    background-size: conver;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    width: 100%;
    height: 20rem;
}

h1 {
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 8rem;
    color: #fff;
    margin-top: 30vh;
}

h2 {
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 2rem;
}

h3 {
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 1.5rem;
    margin: 0rem;
}

.compra {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-between;
    padding: 2rem;
}

.agregar {
    margin: 0;
}

.agregar button {
    width: 5rem;
    border: none;
    align-items: center;
    background-color: #EAE7DE;
    cursor: pointer;
}

.agregar img {
    width: 2rem;
    height: 2rem;
    margin: 0;
}
.seleccion {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
}

.seleccion input {
    border: none;
    background-color: #EAE7DE;
    width: 8rem;
    height: 2rem;
    font-size: 2rem;
    text-align: center;
}

.gridform {
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: repeat(3, 1fr);
    gap: 2rem;
    justify-items: center;
}

.gridFactura {
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: repeat(2, 1fr);
    gap: 2rem;
    grid-template-rows: repeat(3, 1fr);
    font-size: 2rem;
    justify-items: center;
}

select {
    border: none;
    background-color: #EAE7DE;
    width: 12rem;
    height: 2.5rem;
    font-size: 2rem;
    cursor: pointer;
}

option {
    background: #EAE7DE;
}

.total {
    font-size: 2rem;
}
```

```html
<div class="contenedor">
        <div class="slider Posicionbtn productos">
            <div class="card">
                <div class="img">
                    <img src="img/cards/pexels-aphiwat-chuangchoem-437716.jpg" alt="">
                </div>
                <div class="footer-card">
                    <h2>Café Latte</h2>
                    <h3>Precio : $20</h3>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="card">
                <div class="img">
                    <img src="img/cards/hot-chocolate-1058197_1920.jpg" alt="">
                </div>
                <div class="footer-card">
                    <h2>Chocolate Caliente</h2>
                    <h3>Precio : $10</h3>

                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="card">
                <div class="img">
                    <img src="img/como-preparar-cafe-colombiano-758887.jpg" alt="">
                </div>
                <div class="footer-card">
                    <h2>Vanilla Latte</h2>
                    <h3>Precio : $80</h3>

                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="card">
                <div class="img">
                    <img src="img/cards/coffee-4648041_1920.jpg" alt="">
                </div>
                <div class="footer-card">
                    <h2>Helado Café Mocha</h2>
                    <h3>Precio : $60</h3>

                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="seleccion agregar gridform">
        <input type="text" name="cantidad" id="cantidad">
        <select name="Opcion" id="Opcion">
            <option data-precio="20" value="1">Café Latte</option>
            <option data-precio="10" value="2">Chocolate Caliente</option>
            <option data-precio="80" value="3">Vanilla Latte</option>
            <option data-precio="60" value="4">Helado Café Mocha</option>
        </select>
        <button type="button" id="enviar">
            <img src="img/icon/1485969929-12-plus_78898.svg" alt="">
        </button>
    </div>
    <div class="btns">
        <a href="" class="btn btn-color">Ver mas</a>
    </div>
```

Comment: Te recarga la pagina porque tienes un `form` con un button tipo `submit`.  Si lo que quieres es usar Ajax no necesitas forma ni `submit`.

Comment: si ya gracias..

Comment: Pulsa en [edit] y agrega como tienes ahora el código Javascript para verificarlo.

Comment: ya lo actualice

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tu código Javascript es muy repetitivo, tiene algunos errores y malas prácticas.

Para evitar el bloque `switch ... case` con sendas llamadas a Ajax en cada `case` puedes trasladar esa lógica a un objeto tan simple como este:

```
let mData = {
  1: 20,
  2: 10,
  3: 80,
  4: 60
};
```

Como ves, ahí se asocia cada option (valor de la izquierda), a cada valor a multiplicar según el option (valor de la derecha). Esto, si usas HTML5, podría ponerse incluso como un atributo `data-` en cada option.

Luego, al mezclar Javascript puro con jQuery, te estabas confundiendo al intentar obtener valores con algo como `value()` (propio de jQuery) en código puro. Para evitar confusiones, en este caso he usado sintaxis jQuery en la obtención de valores.

Poner funciones in line es una mala práctica. Aquí asociamos un listener al evento change del select directamente en Javascript, prescindiendo de ese modo de la función in line.

Dado que lo único que realmente cambia es el valor a multiplicar, verás que he creado una variable `postData`, en la que metemos cada valor recuperado y para el valor a multplicar, lo obtenermos del objeto, según el option que se haya seleccionado y luego pasamos ese objeto en la petición Ajax.

Lo único diferente es que aquí, los nombres de clave del objeto son siempre los mismos, pero eso no es malo... todo lo contrario. En tu código original taaaaambién cambiabas eso. Significa que en el servidor taaammmbién tendrías que verificar si la clave se llama `Nombre1` o `Nombre2` o `NombreN`  ... y así por cada clave, lo cual no es para nada práctico.

Espero te sirva, y si tienes alguna duda, pregunta en comentarios.

```js
$(function() {
  /*Evitar funciones in line*/
  $("#Opcion").on('change', function() {
    /*Asociamos cada case a un valor*/
    let mData = {
      1: 20,
      2: 10,
      3: 80,
      4: 60
    };

    let opcion = $('option:selected', this).val();
    let valor = $('#cantidad').val();
    let Nombre = $('option:selected', this).text();

    let postData = {
      cantidad: valor,
      Nombre: Nombre,
      Total: valor * mData[opcion]
    };

    console.log(postData);

    $.ajax({
      url: '../php/procesos/ControlCarrito.php',
      method: 'post',
      dataType: 'json',
      data: postData
    }).done(function(info) {
      console.log(info)
    })

  });

});
```

```css
.areaProductos {
    margin: 2rem;
    width: 100%;
    height: 50rem;
    background: #c7c7c7;
}

.productos {
    display: flex;
    margin: 2rem;
    justify-content: center;
}

.productosgrid {
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: repeat(3, 1fr);
}

.card {
    width: 30rem;
    height: 33rem;
    background: #EAE7DE;
    margin: 3rem;
}

.card img {
    background-position: center;
    background-size: conver;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    width: 100%;
    height: 20rem;
}

h1 {
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 8rem;
    color: #fff;
    margin-top: 30vh;
}

h2 {
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 2rem;
}

h3 {
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 1.5rem;
    margin: 0rem;
}

.compra {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-between;
    padding: 2rem;
}

.agregar {
    margin: 0;
}

.agregar button {
    width: 5rem;
    border: none;
    align-items: center;
    background-color: #EAE7DE;
    cursor: pointer;
}

.agregar img {
    width: 2rem;
    height: 2rem;
    margin: 0;
}
.seleccion {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
}

.seleccion input {
    border: none;
    background-color: #EAE7DE;
    width: 8rem;
    height: 2rem;
    font-size: 2rem;
    text-align: center;
}

.gridform {
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: repeat(3, 1fr);
    gap: 2rem;
    justify-items: center;
}

.gridFactura {
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: repeat(2, 1fr);
    gap: 2rem;
    grid-template-rows: repeat(3, 1fr);
    font-size: 2rem;
    justify-items: center;
}

select {
    border: none;
    background-color: #EAE7DE;
    width: 12rem;
    height: 2.5rem;
    font-size: 2rem;
    cursor: pointer;
}

option {
    background: #EAE7DE;
}

.total {
    font-size: 2rem;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="contenedor">
  <div class="slider Posicionbtn productos">
    <div class="card">
      <div class="img">
        <img src="img/cards/pexels-aphiwat-chuangchoem-437716.jpg" alt="">
      </div>
      <div class="footer-card">
        <h2>Café Latte</h2>
        <h3>Precio : $20</h3>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="card">
      <div class="img">
        <img src="img/cards/hot-chocolate-1058197_1920.jpg" alt="">
      </div>
      <div class="footer-card">
        <h2>Chocolate Caliente</h2>
        <h3>Precio : $10</h3>

      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="card">
      <div class="img">
        <img src="img/como-preparar-cafe-colombiano-758887.jpg" alt="">
      </div>
      <div class="footer-card">
        <h2>Vanilla Latte</h2>
        <h3>Precio : $80</h3>

      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="card">
      <div class="img">
        <img src="img/cards/coffee-4648041_1920.jpg" alt="">
      </div>
      <div class="footer-card">
        <h2>Helado Café Mocha</h2>
        <h3>Precio : $60</h3>

      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="seleccion">
  <form id="mform" action="" method="POST" class="agregar gridform">
    <input type="text" name="cantidad" id="cantidad">
    <select name="Opcion" id="Opcion">
      <option value="1">Café Latte</option>
      <option value="2">Chocolate Caliente</option>
      <option value="3">Vanilla Latte</option>
      <option value="4">Helado Café Mocha</option>
    </select>
    <button type="submit" name="submit" id="enviar">
                    <img src="img/icon/1485969929-12-plus_78898.svg" alt="">
                </button>
  </form>
</div>
<div class="btns">
  <a href="" class="btn btn-color">Ver mas</a>
</div>
```

---

Veamos un ejemplo basado en [atributos data](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Learn/HTML/Howto/Use_data_attributes) (HTML 5+).

Aquí simplemente agregamos el precio en un atributo `data-precio` en cada  `option`, quedando así:

```
    <select name="Opcion" id="Opcion">
      <option data-precio="20" value="1">Café Latte</option>
      <option data-precio="10" value="2">Chocolate Caliente</option>
      <option data-precio="80" value="3">Vanilla Latte</option>
      <option data-precio="60" value="4">Helado Café Mocha</option>
    </select>
```

Gracias a eso, podremos ahorrarnos el `switch ... case` inicial y también el objeto `mData`, pudiendo acceder al valor con algo como `mSelect.data('precio')` (estilo jQuery):

```js
$(function() {
  /*Evitar funciones in line*/
  $('#Opcion').on('change', function() {
    /*Referencia al option seleccionado*/
    let mSelect=$('option:selected', this);
    let opcion = mSelect.val();
    let Nombre = mSelect.text();
    let valor = $('#cantidad').val();
    
    let postData = {
      cantidad: valor,
      Nombre: Nombre,
      Total: valor * mSelect.data('precio')
    };

    console.log(postData);

    $.ajax({
      url: '../php/procesos/ControlCarrito.php',
      method: 'post',
      dataType: 'json',
      data: postData
    }).done(function(info) {
      console.log(info)
    })

  });

});
```

```css
.areaProductos {
    margin: 2rem;
    width: 100%;
    height: 50rem;
    background: #c7c7c7;
}

.productos {
    display: flex;
    margin: 2rem;
    justify-content: center;
}

.productosgrid {
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: repeat(3, 1fr);
}

.card {
    width: 30rem;
    height: 33rem;
    background: #EAE7DE;
    margin: 3rem;
}

.card img {
    background-position: center;
    background-size: conver;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    width: 100%;
    height: 20rem;
}

h1 {
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 8rem;
    color: #fff;
    margin-top: 30vh;
}

h2 {
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 2rem;
}

h3 {
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 1.5rem;
    margin: 0rem;
}

.compra {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-between;
    padding: 2rem;
}

.agregar {
    margin: 0;
}

.agregar button {
    width: 5rem;
    border: none;
    align-items: center;
    background-color: #EAE7DE;
    cursor: pointer;
}

.agregar img {
    width: 2rem;
    height: 2rem;
    margin: 0;
}
.seleccion {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
}

.seleccion input {
    border: none;
    background-color: #EAE7DE;
    width: 8rem;
    height: 2rem;
    font-size: 2rem;
    text-align: center;
}

.gridform {
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: repeat(3, 1fr);
    gap: 2rem;
    justify-items: center;
}

.gridFactura {
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: repeat(2, 1fr);
    gap: 2rem;
    grid-template-rows: repeat(3, 1fr);
    font-size: 2rem;
    justify-items: center;
}

select {
    border: none;
    background-color: #EAE7DE;
    width: 12rem;
    height: 2.5rem;
    font-size: 2rem;
    cursor: pointer;
}

option {
    background: #EAE7DE;
}

.total {
    font-size: 2rem;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="contenedor">
  <div class="slider Posicionbtn productos">
    <div class="card">
      <div class="img">
        <img src="img/cards/pexels-aphiwat-chuangchoem-437716.jpg" alt="">
      </div>
      <div class="footer-card">
        <h2>Café Latte</h2>
        <h3>Precio : $20</h3>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="card">
      <div class="img">
        <img src="img/cards/hot-chocolate-1058197_1920.jpg" alt="">
      </div>
      <div class="footer-card">
        <h2>Chocolate Caliente</h2>
        <h3>Precio : $10</h3>

      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="card">
      <div class="img">
        <img src="img/como-preparar-cafe-colombiano-758887.jpg" alt="">
      </div>
      <div class="footer-card">
        <h2>Vanilla Latte</h2>
        <h3>Precio : $80</h3>

      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="card">
      <div class="img">
        <img src="img/cards/coffee-4648041_1920.jpg" alt="">
      </div>
      <div class="footer-card">
        <h2>Helado Café Mocha</h2>
        <h3>Precio : $60</h3>

      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="seleccion">
  <form id="mform" action="" method="POST" class="agregar gridform">
    <input type="text" name="cantidad" id="cantidad">
    <select name="Opcion" id="Opcion">
      <option data-precio="20" value="1">Café Latte</option>
      <option data-precio="10" value="2">Chocolate Caliente</option>
      <option data-precio="80" value="3">Vanilla Latte</option>
      <option data-precio="60" value="4">Helado Café Mocha</option>
    </select>
    <button type="submit" name="submit" id="enviar">
                    <img src="img/icon/1485969929-12-plus_78898.svg" alt="">
                </button>
  </form>
</div>
<div class="btns">
  <a href="" class="btn btn-color">Ver mas</a>
</div>
```

Comment: HAA ok , si sabia que era lo que hacia era una mala practica pero pues así me lo pedían intentare. con las opciones que mediste gracias.

Comment: si quiero mandar el valor del mData tendria que poner algo asi:                                let postData = {
      Nombre: Nombre,
      cantidad: valor,
      Precio:mData[opcion],
      Total: valor * mData[opcion],
      
    };

Comment: si me funciono solo que ahora no manda los datos al archivo de php

Comment: ¿Sigue sin mandar los datos @BryanRL?

Comment: sip intente poner un alert antes de invocar a ajax y lo hace pero si lo pongo dentro de ajax despues del .done no sale el alert al parecer no entrar a ajax